# OMPL MoveIt! error in Kinetic

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 16.04,
ROS Kinetic

Hey, I'm trying to use moveIt with ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm just starting with MoveIt...

After configuring the robot with the moveit_setup_assistant, when I try to run the generated `demo.launch` I get

```
[ERROR] [1502554018.960375858]: Exception while loading planner 'ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner': Failed to load library /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/libmoveit_ompl_planner_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = libompl.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory). 
Available plugins: ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
```

And later

```
[ WARN] [1502554019.325665808]: MoveGroup running was unable to load ompl_interface/OMPLPlanner
```

I have installed moveIt, by installing the `ros-kinetic-moveit` package, it seems like the `ros-kinetic-moveit-planners-ompl` and `ros-kinetic-moveit-planners` are also installed.

`libompl` is also installed, but not version 12 as it appears to be required... when I try to install `libompl12` I get an `Unable to locate package error`.

The rviz part seems to work, I can move the robot, etc. just the planning module is not working...

Any advices?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268649/ompl-moveit!-error-in-kinetic/) by [Matt_krainski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31561/matt_krainski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The correct OMPL package for the binary builds distributed in ROS kinetic is `ros-kinetic-ompl` which installs the missing library as `/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libompl.so.12`

You probably decided to use a different one. In this case you will have to build your own MoveIt packages.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Matt_krainski](https://answers.ros.org/users/31561/matt_krainski/) on 2017-08-13**:
Thanks for the answer.

I've had `ros-kinetic-ompl` installed...

It's interesting - it didn't work at the beginning (even before I've tried to install `libompl`), but started now after I've purged `libompl` and `ros-kinetic-ompl`, and reinstalled `ros-kinetic-moveit`.

**Comment by [Maverobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/31254/maverobot/) on 2018-01-29**:
I followed @Matt_krainski 's suggestion but it did not work. However, it works after restarting the PC.